# What comes after sorting eigenvalues in PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

I'm a student, I have to build PCA from scratch using Matlab on iris data. Iris data have 4 features, I want to reduce them to 2. I reached the sorting of eigenvalues step. What is the next step?

Comment: The basic idea is that you only use the two highest eigenvalues

Comment: I agree with @Omnomnomnom but in general you would choose the number of eigenvalues to maintains $95\%$ of the variation. But since you require a reduction to 2 features in the space that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the two largest eigenvalues and find their corresponding eigenvectors. Then make a matrix that has these eigenvectors as columns. Use that matrix to project your original data.